# What's the difference between width:100% and min-width:100%

Tags: html, css

What's the difference between `width:100%` and `min-width:100%` for `body`?

```css
body{
    width:100%
}
```

and

```css
body{
    min-width:100%
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? StackOverflow is not meant for open ended questions.

Comment: For starters, `min-width` would still allow the body to grow beyond the viewport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the `width` parameter for body, the page size will always be the size of your screen. At the same time if you set `min-width` parameter for body it will be the same size as your screen but it can increase. This is hard to see, but if we were to change the screen size the difference would be visible.

### without `min-width`

```css
.a {
   border: 5px solid red;
   width: 5%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 1rem;
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="margin: 0; font-family: verdana;">
  <div class="a">
     1234567890
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### with `min-width`

```css
.a {
   border: 5px solid red;
   min-width: 5%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 1rem;
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="margin: 0; font-family: verdana;">
  <div class="a">
     1234567890
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[More info](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-width/#:%7E:text=The%20min%2Dwidth%20property%20in,they%20are%20a%20positive%20value.)